# How do you get a triangle hover effect on a pure css navbar?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I would like to have a little triangle underneath the the text that points up when the user hovers over the different tabs.  Here is a bit of code I'm working with.

[css navbar](http://jsfiddle.net/88Uxw/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.tab {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.tab:hover {
  background: #a0a0a0;
}

.tab:hover span {
  display: block;
}

.tab_child {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fff;
}

.selected {
  background: #a0a0a0;
}

.contain * {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}

span.triangle {
  background-image: url("http://www.inner.org/torah_and_science/mathematics/images/triangle.gif");
  background-repeat: none;
  display: none;
  height: 14px;
  width: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div id="one" class="tab selected">Link1</div>
  <div id="two" class="tab">Link2</div>
  <div id="three" class="tab">Link3</div>
  <div id="four" class="tab">Link4</div>
  <div id="five" class="tab">Link5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What part are you having a problem with?

Comment: Here's how to make a CSS triangle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work - You could put it in your tab-div and play around with the color of the triangle (same as background = invisible, change the color on hover, etc.)

Comment: I guess thats the part im having trouble with, anytime I add a triangle in there is screw everything up.  Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/88Uxw/2/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is probably what you're looking for:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/ZRtHF/)

**Also, please use semantic markup:**

1. If your using HTML5 wrap your navigation in `<nav>` tags.
2. Your links (if they really are going to be links) should be `<a>` elements.
3. For a list of links like you have it is advised to use a list (`<ul>` & `<li>`).

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

nav a:hover,
.active {
  background: #bbb;
}

nav a:hover:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border: 12px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/FEZ3g/) is a modification to your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88Uxw/2):

I've added a `<span class="arrow"></span>` to contain the triangles in the HTML:

```
<div class="tab_container">
    <div id="test1-header" class="accordion_headings header_highlight" >Home<span class="arrow"></span></div>
    <div id="test2-header" class="accordion_headings" >About<span class="arrow"></span></div>
    <div id="test3-header" class="accordion_headings" >Work<span class="arrow"></span></div>
    <div id="test4-header" class="accordion_headings" >Social<span class="arrow"></span></div>
    <div id="test5-header" class="accordion_headings" >Contact<span class="arrow"></span></div>
</div>
```

Here are the changes made to your menu which reduce the size of the triangle and position them at the bottom center of each menu item when hovered over:
CSS:

```
/*
.accordion_headings:hover{
    background:#00CCFF;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
*/
.accordion_headings{
    position:relative;
}
.accordion_headings .arrow{
    display:none;
}
.accordion_headings:hover .arrow{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;

    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:49%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwelch/88Uxw/22/) that uses an background-image that will display over the hovered menu item. It not pretty but further css should help with that.

## UPDATE

Sorry I must have misread that. Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwelch/88Uxw/22/) with a smaller arrow pointing in the proper direction.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but I don't see anything in chrome.

Comment: "I would like to have a little triangle underneath the the text that points up when the user hovers over the different tabs." How does your solution answer that?

Comment: My understanding of a "pure css navbar" means to exclude images.

Comment: I thought it was just not using any scripting. I would agree this is does not fit that requirement.