# Hover Menu - Active Menu - CSS

Tags: css, menu

for the first time i made a jquery slider using [coda slider](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.html).

but i want to customize the menu, i want a little a arrow that will show on the top of the *li a* when you hover it and if it's active.

How will i do that? should i use a image? or can i achieve the effect using css3?

```
<ul class="navigation">
<li><a href="#sites">Sites</a></li>
<li><a href="#files">Files</a></li>
<li><a href="#editor">Editor</a></li>
```

```
<style>
.navigation {
padding:0px;
margin-bottom:90px;
}

ul.navigation li {
list-style-type:none;
}

ul.navigation li a {
text-decoration:none;
float:left;
width:254px;
height:50px;
display:block;
background-color:#ccc;
text-align:center;
line-height:40px;
}

ul.navigation li a:hover {
background-color:#666;
  /*there should be some sort of background image here or css3? */
}

.active {
   /*there should be some sort of background image here or css3? */
}
<style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.selected:hover {
  /* you can use CSS3 to make arrows or image both */
}
```

After analyzing, I observed, that plugin adds `.selected` class to that `li` element which is selected. So, you can also use CSS3 to make arrows by using `:after` and `:before` psuedo classes with `display:none` and show only on hover of `.selected`.

Comment: and this question helped me to achieve the triangle effect using css3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841301/how-do-you-get-a-triangle-hover-effect-on-a-pure-css-navbar

Answer (score 1):

```
   ul.navigation li a:active {  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.navigation > li:hover > a,
ul.navigation > li > a:active,
ul.navigation > li > a.selected {
    /* do whatever */
}
```

Just in case you have a sub menu, I used the direct descendant selector (>).